# How can i enable service worker in dev mode in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I know that we can test our service worker in production mode, but the proccess of re-building and deploying is quite annoying. Is there some way to enable serive worker in dev mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;


      console.log("file location" + swUrl);
      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
```

with this

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      console.log("file location" + swUrl);

        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);

    });
```

in your serviceWorker.js file

also put replace this

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
```

with this

```
if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
```

notice its checking for prod so removing that condition will start service worker on local also

Comment: It worked but it didn't cache the static file like in production mode. I don't think `service-worker.js` exists in dev mode

Comment: All this will become tricky with default service worker. Will suggest you to right your own service worker either vanilla or with workbox.

Comment: My problem is that the server does not return the service worker: `http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js` return the index.html