# Why does my create-react-app have no service workers?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, service-worker, scaffolding

I used the simplest and the dumbest command

```
npx create-react-app mia-app
cd mia-app
npm start
```

But after created the project everytime there are no serviceWorker. Can someone help me?

[image]
[image]

However, I've tried with `npm create-create-app` with this res.

[image]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your file structure you got.

Comment: can you try:
npm uninstall create-react-app
npm install create-react-app@latest

then try again

Comment: @NanoAdam I've just added photos into question

Comment: @SinanYaman I'think npm for cra it's deprecated.. i've updated the description

Comment: after you install with npm install create-react-app you should just use create-react-app scem instead of npm create-react-app ...

Comment: @SinanYaman the React docs recommend you use `npx` rather than installing create-react-app locally (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) "to ensure that npx always uses the latest version".

Comment: Oh I see, well my only guess is npm being out of date then

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10104 there's a GitHub issue open on this - `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa` is a suggested workaround.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley absolutely fantastic, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`serviceWorker.js` is no longer included in the base template, as of create-react-app version 4.0.something.

Trawling through the create-react-app GitHub issues, two main workarounds keep popping up:

1. [Create an app using the following template](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9776#issuecomment-721800558):

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

or for Typescript:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript
```

(where `my-app` is replaced by the name of your app)

2. If you already have an existing project, [create a dummy app and copy over the relevant code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9776#issuecomment-728945921). Don't forget to copy over the initialisation code from index.js/index.tsx if you do this too.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to change the call to `unregister` to `register` in `serviceWorkerRegistration.ts`. However, even after I did that, I didn't see a service worker show up. After looking at the `register` function, I realized that the service worker won't run on non-prod build so you'll have to address this issue [How can i enable service worker in dev mode in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175019/how-can-i-enable-service-worker-in-dev-mode-in-create-react-app) if you want to see it with `npm start`. This is an unresolved issue as dev mode does not serve up service-worker.js

Answer (score -1):

For who have the same problem as suggested by [James Whiteley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8230810/james-whiteley)
you can use the following command

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template <app-name>
```

For more info check this github issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10104